Is it possible to achieve both detection and image classification by training the model on the custom dataset?
I am beginning to work on a non-linear navigation system for educational videos as a part of my undergrad coursework project. As a part of it, I need to classify the unique frames (frame which is slide, handwritten, only figure, with both text and figure, only text, blank frame) and also need to segment (here also I have a question, is it a segmentation task or should I go with multi-object detection) the content of the frame (text, figure, title, figure title). I would like to do this using a single model trained on a single custom dataset. But I am not sure about the practicality of this.
I have some questions regarding this:

I am not sure how I should prepare the dataset for this task.
Whether I could use annotation &its labels and class labels in the
same dataset?
Can I train the model on the dataset (if the answer to
1 is yes) only once to achieve both tasks? Do I need to make any
other changes to the model except some changes to the final layer?

Thank you in advance!

How you approach this task depends what model or framework you are using but generally sharing parameters is a good idea. what I recommend you do is something like this (what im putting below is a rough outline throw it in chat gpt and it will get it) the idea being that you can separate segmentation and categorization to make the job of making a dataset easier for yourself. You should be able to pass in even differently sized batches of Segmentation data and Categorization data without issue.:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
class MultiTaskModel(nn.Module):
def init(self, num_layers, hidden_dim, num_categories, image_size):
super(MultiTaskModel, self).init()
# Define shared processing layers, ideally in a U-Net for segmentation tasks
self.processing_layers = nn.ModuleList([nn.LazyLinear(hidden_dim) for _ in range(num_layers)])
    # Task-specific heads for classification and segmentation
    self.category_head = nn.LazyLinear(num_categories)
    self.segmentation_head = nn.LazyLinear(image_size)  # if you use a conv layer as the output you can have different segmentation channels using the number of filters
    
    # Optimizer setup
    self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=3e-4)

def forward(self, x):
    x = torch.flatten(x.float(), start_dim=1)
    for layer in self.processing_layers:
        x = F.relu(layer(x))
    categories = self.category_head(x)
    segments = self.segmentation_head(x)
    return categories, segments

def train_step(self, Images1, Categories, Images2, Segments):
    self.optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Category prediction and loss calculation
    pred_categories, _ = self(Images1)
    categories_loss = F.cross_entropy(pred_categories, Categories)

    # Segmentation prediction and loss calculation
    _, pred_segments = self(Images2)
    segmentation_loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred_segments, Segments)

    # Combined loss and backpropagation
    loss = categories_loss + segmentation_loss
    loss.backward()
    self.optimizer.step()

